# Python how to control curvature when joining two points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a original curve. I am developing a model curve matching closely the original curve. Everything is working fine but not matching. How to control the curvature of my model curve?  Below code is based on [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008322/draw-a-curve-connecting-two-points-instead-of-a-straight-line).

My code:

```
def curve_line(point1, point2):
    a = (point2[1] - point1[1])/(np.cosh(point2[0]) - np.cosh(point1[0]))
    b = point1[1] - a*np.sinh(point1[0])
    x = np.linspace(point1[0], point2[0],100).tolist()
    y = (a*np.cosh(x) + b).tolist()
    return x,y
###### A sample of my code is given below
point1 = [10,100]
point2 = [20,50]
x,y = curve_line(point1, point2)

plt.plot(point1[0], point1[1], 'o')
plt.plot(point2[0], point2[1], 'o')
plt.plot(x,y)  ## len(x)
```

My present output:

[image]

I tried following function as well:

```
y = (50*np.exp(-x/10) +2.5)
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a parameter to cosh, such as `np.cosh(const * x)` where `const` < 1 if you want a smaller curvature. Also remove both `tolist()` methods because they are unnecessary and will create an error with the change I described.

Comment: @Ardweaden I tried but it did not work. I tried this: `y = (50*np.exp(-x/10) +2.5)` and updated my question above.

Comment: Why didn't it work? Post some of the data from the original curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just guessing the right parameters of your model function, you can fit a model curve to your data using [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([ 1.92, 14.35, 21.50, 25.27, 27.34, 30.32, 32.31, 34.09, 34.21])
y = np.array([8.30, 8.26, 8.13, 7.49, 6.66, 4.59, 2.66, 0.60, 0.06])

def fun(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.cosh(b * x) + c
coef,_ = curve_fit(fun, x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, label='Original curve')
plt.plot(x, fun(x, *coef), label=f'Model: %5.3f cosh(%4.2f x + %4.2f)' % tuple(coef) )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If it is important that the start and end points are closely fitted, you can pass uncertainties to `curve_fit`, adjusting them to lower values towards the ends, e.g. by

```
s = np.ones(len(x))
s[1:-1] = s[1:-1] * 3
coef,_ = curve_fit(fun, x, y, sigma=s)
```

[image]

Your other approach `a * np.exp(b * x) + c` will also work and gives `-0.006 exp(0.21 x + 8.49)`.

In some cases you'll have to provide an educated guess for the initial values of the coefficients to `curve_fit` (it uses `1` as default).

Comment: Here you are doing the curve fit. But I only have information about three points. Nothing more. Could you please check my new question detailing the problem with example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310965/python-join-any-three-given-points-using-a-curve Thanks