How to remove empty date from pandas line chart
I have plotted line graph using pandas and matplotlib. I have timeseries data with some dates missed in between (which is not required).
Dates:
"2024-01-01"
"2024-01-02"
"2024-01-03"
"2024-01-04"
"2024-01-05"
"2024-01-08"
"2024-01-09"
"2024-01-10"
"2024-01-11"
"2024-01-12"
"2024-01-15"
"2024-01-16"
"2024-01-17"
"2024-01-18"
"2024-01-19"
"2024-01-20"

Code:
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(databaseData,columns=['ticker','tdate','ttime','open','high','low','close','volume','openinterest'])
dataframe['tdate'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['tdate'].astype(str) + ' ' + dataframe['ttime'])
dataframe['sma'] = pd.Series(dataframe['close']).rolling(window=3).mean()
dataframe = dataframe.dropna(subset=['close'])
print(dataframe)
dataframe['close'] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe['close'])
dataframe.plot.line(x='tdate',y='close')
plot.show()


In graph how can I remove not required dates and smoothen the graph.
I tried adding x_compat=True in plot, still no luck

What do you mean by smoothen? If you don't want lines between the dates you removed, you can skip the line with .dropna. The break between sub-plots will be created when missing values are in the dataset.

Smoothen means instead of sharp dot connected line I would like to have a curve between each data point.

You can try to implement the approach from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008322/draw-a-curve-connecting-two-points-instead-of-a-straight-line

You can resample the time series to ensure that all dates are included, and then drop or forward-fill missing values if necessary.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create dataframe and combine date and time columns
dataframe['tdate'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['tdate'].astype(str) + ' ' + dataframe['ttime'])
dataframe.set_index('tdate', inplace=True)

# Calculate rolling mean
dataframe['sma'] = dataframe['close'].rolling(window=3).mean()

# Drop rows with missing 'close' and resample to daily frequency
dataframe = dataframe.dropna(subset=['close'])
dataframe_resampled = dataframe.resample('D').last().dropna(subset=['close'])

# Plot the data
dataframe_resampled.plot.line(y='close')
plt.show()

